# Is there a transient type in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5

I am using .net 3.5 framework sp1 and VS 2008 sp1. I have created an edmx model. I couldn't create a transient (which is not persisted to the database) property .

Any ideas?

Comment: I voted to close: "exact duplicate".  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553129/asp-net-entity-framework-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties to a partial class for the type you are interested in adding transient properties to - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738696.aspx).

Comment: As Christopher says, It's possible but probably too much work to use POCO with EF 3.5. I'd either go EF 4 or partial classes if I where you.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Data Model doesn't currently support the idea of transient properties. However as Christopher pointed out, you can create a CLR properties in a partial class, that doesn't map to an Entity property.

This will work fine, but bear in mind all references to that property in LINQ to Entity queries will result in exceptions.